# Can not print pdf using DOMPDF in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use DOMPDF and print tables from my blade templemate, but I have a problem:
 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 251)

How can I print it all?

Here's some code:

```
//controller    
public function survey($id)
        {
            $client = Client::findOrFail($id);

            return View::make('client/print', compact('client'));
        }

        public function survey_print(Request $request, $id)
        {
             $client = Client::findOrFail($id);
            $pdf = \PDF::loadView('client/survey_print', compact('client'));
            return $pdf->download('ankieta.pdf');
        }
```

web.php

```
Route::get('print/{id}', 'ClientController@survey');

Route::post('survey_print/{id}', 'ClientController@survey_print');
```

Comment: I guess the problem is in `post`. Why do you use for a print post method?